# How to add a prefix to all numbers based on the number of digit of the greatest number?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have created a directory listing of my google drive in cloudfare index.
The file sorting logic  is pretty weird for some reason.
It sorts file in sequence from 0 for every digit and if digit number matches , it checks for second digit from 0 and so on..

Currently the files sorted  show up like this from top to bottom
 1  , 10  , 100 ,101..109 , 11 , 110 ,111..119 ,12

There's a easy way to fix it but it needs to me to manually rename each file and add prefix 0  based on the no of digits of greatest number but there are hundreds/thousands of them.
I will be using javascript to rename all my files, it accepts inputting new names in following format , ( oA is the array where i input new names for each file ) .

*I was wondering if any awk/perl/regex function can produce the expected output when executed on file.txt*

**Example 1**

cat file.text

```
oA=['Lecture 7 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 56 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 3 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 4 - Topic.mp4']
```

Expected Output

```
oA=['Lecture 07 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 56 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 03 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 04 - Topic.mp4']
```

**Example 2**

cat file.txt

```
oA=['Lecture 3 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 116 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 46 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 112 - Topic.mp4']
```

Expected output

```
oA=['Lecture 003 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 116 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 046 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 112 - Topic.mp4']
```

**Example 3**

cat file.txt

```
oA=['Lecture 8 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 1165 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 667 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 12 - Topic.mp4']
```

Expected output

```
oA=['Lecture 0008 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 1165 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 0667 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 0012 - Topic.mp4']
```

As you might have noticed , only prefx 0 should be added to each number as required , the order of Lectures is still preseverd ( its important )

If i had to explain it like this...

1) Grab the greatest number after the word Lecture and check its no of digits.
2) Now all the numbers will have same no of digits as the greatest number ,add prefix zeros to each number as necessary

Comment: It's sorting lexicographically, not numerically, btw. Depending on what is being used to sort your file listing, there might be a way to sort in other ways without having to rename the files.

Comment: @Shawn thanks for answering  , especially i didn't knew what this way of sorting is called.  Good to know it now , Although i don't know of any way to change sorting method for this cloudfare worker index , it might be possible but will have to dig quite deeper, i will try it sometime.   For now i would say manipulating numbers will do the job

Comment: The following is an implementation in Ruby, which should be easily transferable to one of the languages mentioned. `R = /(?<=\ALecture )\d+/; def convert(arr); mx = arr.map { |s| s[R].size }.max; arr.map { |s| s.gsub(R) { |t| t.rjust(mx, '0') } }; end`. The argument of the method `convert` is an array such as those defined as `oA` in the examples. `mx` is the size of the longest string of digits following `'Lecture '`. The method `rjust` is defined [thusly](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-rjust).

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to fix the listing order, or to rename the files ? Renaming files on google drive will require more effort just fixing the list

Comment: @dash-o rename the files obviously.   You can compare the expected output with original text

Comment: @dash-o yes i agree but its not google drive listing method.  Its cloudfare index worker sorting.  Gdrive seems to sort them numerically but i had have to adjust it for sorting properly on cloudfare index

Comment: Can you post your 'rename' script (or abbreviated version). It will be easier to suggest a solution that works well with the rename logic. Can you clarify the input array - what scripting engine do you have the 'oA=[....]' - is it awk, Perl, or shell array

Comment: @dash-o sure , why not. Here's the whole renane script - https://del.dog/crappanoon.txt . I will be running it on script.google.com to rename all files. The line i have posted in question is the newname input present ie .OA=... in the first line of script , i hope you have understood now

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I understand you are looking for a way to generate the 'oa' array that you can feed into the appscript/javascript code. Much clearer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Perl, the solution boils down to the repetition operator `x`.**  In the code below, the crucial line is

`my $padding = "0" x ($maxlen-$thislen);`

The [Perl documentation on operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) says this about `x`: "In scalar context or if the left operand is not enclosed in parentheses, it returns a string consisting of the left operand repeated the number of times specified by the right operand."

So it will repeat the digit 0 enough times to make a number of length `$thislen` into a number of length `$maxlen`.

The code gives the correct output for each of the examples.

```
$ cat file.text
oA=['Lecture 7 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 56 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 3 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 4 - Topic.mp4']
iA=['Lecture 3 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 116 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 46 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 112 - Topic.mp4']
anyname=['Lecture 8 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 1165 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 667 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 12 - Topic.mp4']

$ ./padding.pl file.text
oA=['Lecture 07 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 56 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 03 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 04 - Topic.mp4']
iA=['Lecture 003 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 116 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 046 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 112 - Topic.mp4']
anyname=['Lecture 0008 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 1165 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 0667 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 0012 - Topic.mp4']
```

**Here is the full code that performs the requested task.**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Usage: 
#   padding.pl [file1.text [file2.text [...]]]

use List::Util qw(max);
use strict;

my $varname = "";
my @oA = ();

# loop over lines in input file(s)
while ($_ = <>) {

  # Put data in @oA array.
  # You'll need to decide what assumptions to make 
  # about your input data.
  chomp;
  ($varname) = /^([^=]*)=/;
  s/^$varname=//g;
  if (/^\['.*'\]$/)  {
    s/^\['|'\]$//g;
    @oA = split( /','/, $_ );
  }

  # extract the numbers, find the max
  my @oA_nums = map { /Lecture (\d+)/; $1 } @oA;
  my $maxlen = max map(length,@oA_nums); # pad all oA to this length

  # replace the numbers with padded versions
  foreach my $i (0 .. $#oA) {                 # loop from 0 to "num elements - 1"
    my $thislen = length($oA_nums[$i]);
    my $padding = "0" x ($maxlen-$thislen);   # THIS IS IT!
    my $padded_num = $padding . $oA_nums[$i];

    $oA[$i] =~ s/Lecture \d+/Lecture $padded_num/;
  }

  print "$varname=['";
  print join "','", @oA;
  print "']\n";

}
```

Comment: Hello sir , i needed a very small help regarding this answer ,can you please read it here - https://del.dog/raw/ogirfimorr

Answer (score 1):

Given script will be running in GoogleApp, see the following Javascript solution. It wil lcreate oA, from iA

1. find the longest sequence
2. loop over document, replace sequence with zero-padded sequence, put in oA

The console.log is for verification. Remove, and use the rename method you already have after testing.

```
iA=['Lecture 7 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 56 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 3 - Topic.mp4','Lecture 4 - Topic.mp4']
let seq_len=1

// Collect sequence, find largest
for (doc of iA) {
        let seq = doc.match("\\d+")[0]
        if ( seq.length > seq_len ) seq_len = seq.length
}

oA=[]
for (doc of iA) {
        let old_seq = doc.match("\\d+")[0]
        let new_seq = old_seq
        while ( new_seq.length < seq_len ) new_seq = "0" + new_seq
        oA.push( doc.replace(old_seq, new_seq))
}

console.log(seq_len)
console.log (oA)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ,i ran the js code but the oA isn't being generated in required format ie ( in 1 line like the iA is present ) .You can check the output here - https://del.dog/pebalelofu.txt

Comment: Also the square opening and ending brackets have an extra space , i can do this manually but just stating

Comment: FYI: The output follows Javascript rules. You do not have to put all the items of the array on one output into your code.  My other comment is that this is just a code, you can integrated it into your other sniplet (that one that performs the rename)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution - Perl.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use List::Util qw(max) ;

while ( <> ) {
        if ( s/^iA=/oA=/ ) {
                my $maxlen = max(map { length } /Lecture (\d+)/g) ;
                s/(Lecture )(\d+)/sprintf("%s %0${maxlen}d", $1, $2)/eg ;
                print ;
        }
}
```